# working out do while loops

Tags: c

I'm working inside a do...while loop. I need some fixing of the codes.

The program that I have is this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    void main()

     {

       int n, score, ctr=1, total=0, ts=0;
       float average=0;

       printf("\n\nEnter How Many Scores: ");
       scanf("%d",&n);

       do{

            printf("\nEnter score %d: ",ctr++);
            scanf("%d",&score);
            total+=score;
            average=total/n;
            if(score>=50&&100<=score);
              printf("\nTotal Score from 50-100: %d",score);
            if(score%2==0);
              printf("\nTotal even number score: %d",score);
            if(score%2!=0);
              printf("\nTotal odd number score: %d",score);

       }while(ctr<=n);
         printf("\nTotal Score: %d",total);
         printf("\nAverage: %.2f",average);

       getch();

    }
```

All I need to find is the total score from 50-100, the total even number score and the total odd number score. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I don't get the total score from 50-100, total even score and total odd score. I want to get the total of them but I don't know how.

Comment: I left you an answer but it is just to give you an idea. you need to get rid of semicolons after if statements.

Comment: `void main()` is no valid signature and **also** no prototype-style declarator.

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indention.

Comment: learning `else` keyword will greatly benefit you...

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help me with this but I have now found the correct program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could use separate variables for total score, total even score and total odd score. Then in the condition check update the corresponding total variables.

```
int total_fh = 0, total_es = 0, total_os = 0;

if (score >=50 && score <= 100) 
{
    total_fh += score;

    if (score % 2 == 0) {
        total_es += score;
    }
    else if (score % 2 != 0) 
    {
        total_os += score;
    }
 }
```

Then outside the loop, print the scores using `printf` statements.

Comment: What does "total_fh" stands for?

Comment: total_fh stands for fifty hundred. Insane name maybe; but this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: possible logical error: this will not increment even and odd scores if they fall between 50 and 100

Comment: It will have errors. Please expand your codes

Comment: @ForeverStudent Thanks for the edits. Missed the braces :)

Comment: @aliasm2k Thanks man. It really worked and even though that I change the values into lower than the range of 50 it will still compute. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you have `if(score>=50&&100<=score);`

you need to change it to `if(score>=50 && score<=100)` if you want score between 50 and 100.

also you need to get rid of semicolons after the if statements.

In addition, if you want to calculate the total number of even and odd scores, you will need to keep track of those with a separate variable for each. like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, score, ctr=1, total=0, ts=0;
    float average=0;
    int odds=0;
    int evens=0;

    printf("\n\nEnter How Many Scores: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    do{
        printf("\nEnter score %d: ",ctr++);
        scanf("%d",&score);
        total+=score;

        if(score>=50 && score<=100 )
        printf("\nTotal Score from 50-100: %d",score);
        if(score%2==0)
        {
            evens++;
            printf("\nTotal even score: %d",evens);
        }
        if(score%2!=0)
        {
            odds++;
             printf("\nTotal odd score: %d",odds);
        }
    }while(ctr<=n);

    printf("\nTotal Score: %d",total);


    if((odds+evens) !=0) average= (float) total/(odds+evens);
          printf("\nAverage: %.2f", average );
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You should use standard `int main(void)` instead of implementation-defined `void main()`

Comment: correct, I was only editing his code on the fly

Comment: The sum of "The total score from 50-100" won't come up. It will just print the last number inputted

Comment: it is unclear what functionality you want excatly. The code I wrote is valid C code syntactically.

Comment: Sorry @ForeverStudent. My english is bad. What I want is the program will compute "The total score from 50-100" so it means that it will only recognize the scores that is inside the ranges 50 to 100 and sum up the scores (not count on how many scores that ranges from 50-100) . So as the odd and even. Recognize what inputted score is odd/even then sum up all of the odd/even scores.